# Combining and slicing 2 querysets before hitting the database in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to get a queryset from mergeing two querysets. The conditions are as follows:

- Pull only 20 items
- Hit the database only once
- The resulting queryset must have the same objects as my code in this question produces

Lets say I have a model called MyModel, with a field called value which stores integers, however, the value can be null.

I know querysets in Django are lazy, but Im not sure if the conditions are being met in the following line of code.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.exclude(value__isnull=True).filter(value__gte=250).order_by('-value') | MyModel.objects.exclude(value__isnull=False)
objects = qs[:20]
```

Basically, I am filtering out first where the value is not null, ordering them according to value, and then at the end, I am adding the ones excluded. Is this meeting my conditions? That is, is the database being hit once? Moreover, is there a better way to do this without the `|` operator?

Note: I know this can be done without merging querysets, but for the sake of this question, lets assume that having 2 querysets like this is absolutely necessary.

Edit: Added third condition, which I thought was implied. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works as you say.
[This](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3957f767bb215bbd4ca48aabdf068fdd214aa79c/django/db/models/query.py#L315) is undocumented implementation of union of querysets. It will hit the database only once.

You can verify that it is coerced into one query with by `print(qs.query)`

Also i recommend checking [FAQ: How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries
```

It will allow you to inspect queries that hit database